# I am trying to read the output values from ARM template in post deployment script file. Can you give me the syntax to read those values?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, kudu

I am trying to read the output values from ARM template in post deployment script file. Can you give me the syntax to read those values?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted result?

Comment: As ARM is the starting point and building the Infrastructure based up on the input 
parameters it has to exchange the input/output parameters to the subsequent operation. So far I dont see that Kudu is receiving that information. Did you get to play with it?

Answer (score 0):

You  could retrieve the out value from a [linked template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) by using reference function.

retrieve the property value with syntax like: `"[reference('<name-of-deployment>').outputs.<property-name>.value]"`

> **Note**: You **cannot** use the reference function in the outputs section of a nested template. To return the values for a deployed resource in a nested template, convert your nested template to a linked template.

If Powershell command is possible, we could get the following command

```
$deploy = New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deployment -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -TemplateFile $deployJsonFilePath -TemplateParameterFile $deployJsonParameterFilePath 
$outPuts = $deploy.Outputs
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But in my case, running the ARM template file from power shell is not at all an option. I am invoking the template from GitHub (Deploy to Azure) button. If I use the linked template with the "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments", will the linked template outputs accessible from KUDU postdeployactions script like batch/shell?